# How can we pass whole array in #define as argument?

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, c-preprocessor

I've confusion in one syntax, Just want to know different between below two syntax.

```
#define objKeys @[@"key1",@"key2",@"key3"]
#define dicWithValue1(val1,val2,val3) [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[val1,val2,val3] forKeys:objKeys]
#define dicWithValue2(objArray) [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objArray forKeys:objKeys]

-(void)someFunction
{
    NSMutableArray *arrValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [arrValues addObject:dicWithValue1(@"val1",@"val2",@"val3")];  // STATEMENT 1
    [arrValues addObject:dicWithValue1(@[@"val1",@"val2",@"val3"])]; // STATEMENT 2

    // Below Statements will give error... for Multiple Arguments..
    [arrValues addObject:dicWithValue2(@"val1",@"val2",@"val3")];  // STATEMENT 3
    [arrValues addObject:dicWithValue2(@[@"val1",@"val2",@"val3"])]; // STATEMENT 4

}
```

Question 1 : Statement 2 will crash app at run time, but it's not giving any error on compile time. So, What is the difference between Statement 1 and Statement 2?

Question 2 : How can we pass array object in #define function, As Statement 3 and 4 giving Compilation Error for multiple arguments.

Answer (score 3):

First a hint, you can run the preprocessor on a file using gcc -E, this will expand all your macros to make it very easy to see where your problem is:

gcc -E -o outfile.m myFile.m

If you take the code that you've written put it in a file and run this command you'll have all the error messages regarding your problem. If you have questions about your error messages then you could ask them.

You're getting stuck with some of what you're doing because macros can't ignore the commas. So `@[@"val1",@"val2",@"val3"]` passes three arguments to the macro i.e. arg1: `@[@"val1"` arg2: `@"val2"` arg3: `@"val3"]` you can solve this with parentheses by doing:

`(@[@"val1", @"val2", @"val3"])`

```
[arrValues addObject:dicWithValue2((@[@"val1",@"val2",@"val3"]))]; \\Statement 4
```

[Here's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html) the documentation with a section about the comma problem.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Statement 2 will crash as you have a different number of keys and values.  The compiler doesn't know that the number of elements in the arrays should be equal and it has no way of finding out; hence it's a requirement that can only be enforced at runtime.

Question 2:

I don't really understand the question given Statement 1 already shows how to pass as array from a compiler constant.  I would suggest you avoid such complicated macros as they can be more trouble than they are worth.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

dicWithValue1 is expecting three values.

Statement 1 does that, but Statement 2 does not (it passes one value that is an array of 3 objects).

You can use either Statement 1 or statement 4.

**Question 2:**

What is the compilation error description?

You may have to cast `objArray` to an array here: `dictionaryWithObjects:objArray`

Answer (score 0):

I think @trojanfoe is right.

**Answer 1:**

Statement 2 will fail as number of parameters are not defined until runtime, also it will still crash as you are passing just one parameter instead of three.

**Answer 2:**

Statement 3 is not correct for the same reason as above i.e. you are passing invalid number of parameters.
Statement 4 will also not work as number of parameters are not defined until runtime.

You can however try this code to make it work:

```
NSArray* tempArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abc", @"def", @"ghi", nil];
[arrValues addObject:dicWithValue2(tempArray)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer lies in the mechanism of how compiler resolves the argument data type and number of arguments in macro declaration. I am not expert in the subject but it seems that there is some issue in compiler resolving the no of arguments to a function in compile time.

In statement 2, if you reduce/increase 1 argument, compiler will throw error for mismatched arguments. Though it is only one argument and this is acknowledged in run time with crash because remaining two arguments are `nil`. Statement2 doesn't provide the exact no of argument that function is expecting. That's why the crash.

For the same reason, compiler is not able to calculate the argument count in statement 3 and 4.

As far as your question 2 solution is concerned you can pass an `NSArray` object to `macro` by creating a local array object and then passing it as argument. See the code below: -

```
NSArray * arrNewValues = @[@"val1",@"val2",@"val3"];
[arrValues addObject:dicWithValue2(arrNewValues)];
```

This way you can silent the compiler by exact match of arguments.